# How to find equidistant colors in different colorspaces?

Tags: plotting, color

I can find equidistant colors in the LAB colorspace. Since, it is complicated, I first calculated the values of a and b for equidistant points on the AB plane and incremented the L values gradually for each point. Below is what I've done so far:

```
getLABColors[n_] := (
      RM = {{Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]]}, {Sin[\[Theta]], 
            Cos[\[Theta]]}};
      coord = {{1}, {1}};
      l = Table[x, {x, 0, 1, 1/(n - 1)}];
      ab = Table[RM.coord, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi , 2 Pi /(n - 1)}];
      a = Table[ab[[i]][[1]][[1]], {i, 1, n, 1}];
      b = Table[ab[[i]][[2]][[1]], {i, 1, n, 1}];
      labcolors = 
          Table[LABColor[N[l[[i]]], N[a[[i]]], N[b[[i]]]], {i, 1, n, 1}]
     );
```

Using this, I can find 6 equidistant colors:

```
labcolors = getLABColors[6]
```

and the result is:

```
{LABColor[0., 1., 1.], LABColor[
 0.2, -0.6420395219202061, 1.260073510670101], LABColor[
 0.4, -1.3968022466674206`, -0.22123174208247431`], LABColor[
 0.6, -0.22123174208247431`, -1.3968022466674206`], LABColor[
 0.8, 1.260073510670101, -0.6420395219202061], LABColor[1., 1., 1.]}
```

When I tried to visualise the points on the 3D Gamut, I found the point lie on the surface of the gamut in the form of a spiral of one complete turn as I wanted.

```
Show[ChromaticityPlot3D["LAB", FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.2]], 
 ChromaticityPlot3D[labcolors, PlotStyle -> PointSize[.02]]]
```

[image]

I tried to do the same with RGB colorspace but did not get the expected result.

```
getRGBColors[n_] := (
   RM = {{Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]]}, {Sin[\[Theta]], 
   Cos[\[Theta]]}};
   coord = {{1}, {1}};
   b = Table[x, {x, 0, 1, 1/(n - 1)}];
   rg = Table[RM.coord, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi , 2 Pi /(n - 1)}];
   r = Sort[Rescale[Table[N[rg[[i]][[1]][[1]]], {i, 1, n, 1}]]];
   g = Sort[Rescale[Table[N[rg[[i]][[2]][[1]]], {i, 1, n, 1}]]];
   rgbcolors = 
   Table[RGBColor[N[r[[i]]], N[g[[i]]], N[b[[i]]]], {i, 1, n, 1}]
 );

 rgbcolors = getRGBColors[6];

Show[ChromaticityPlot3D["RGB", FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.5]], 
ChromaticityPlot3D[rgbcolors, PlotStyle -> PointSize[.02]]]
```

[image]

(a) What is the correct way to fix this?
(b) How can I extend this to other color spaces?
(c) Is it possible to achieve this in a far better and faster way than the approach I have followed?

[It will be a bonus if the color values for the points can be displayed on the chromaticity plot either statically or on mouse hover.]

Comment: What is your definition of `labcolors` being equidistant? Surely all six colors can't be pairwise equidistant from each other.

Comment: @kirma : I agree. I want a list of colors such that the distance between two consecutive colors are same and it utilizes the maximum range of the colorspace.

Comment: I use `Hue /@ Most[Subdivide[n]]` often

Comment: @Majis I have some old code which tries to maximize various measures based on `ColorDistance`, but my experiences with it are not very convincing. I might later clean up some code demonstrating it, though.

Comment: @yode It's really great. But how can it be extended to other color spaces?

Comment: @Majis By `ColorConvert`?

Comment: @yode Yes, this can be done. But this will result in the same colors and not the equidistant colors in the other color spaces. In LAB, the XY plane is the AB plane. If I can find what components are plotted in different axes (X, Y and Z) along with their ranges in other color spaces, it is possible to find the points on the surface of the gamut. But I haven't found any such documentation explaining the construction of this chromaticityplot3D.