# Where can I find the source of data which is used by ChromaticityPlot3D?

Tags: color, implementation-details

This question is related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141825/how-to-find-equidistant-colors-in-different-colorspaces) one. Now I'm interested in the origin of the chromaticity diagrams for different color spaces, which can be found using chromaticityPlot3D. Therefore, I need the original datasets which are used to create the chromaticity diagrams.

Since the shape of the chromaticity diagrams in 3D is not a regular one, it is difficult to find the color values on the surface of the plots.

Even Mathematica documentation doesn't provide any information about the different axes and scaling of the 3D gamuts.

Any help with information or resources is appreciated.